# Try to post table rows back to MVC controller as a List<> object

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

For our site we have an Admin section and a user section. We want to allow Admins to specify which order items are listed to the users in the user section.

I have an MVC list table, and I've enabled sorting the rows to actually change the sort value. But I'm trying to save the sort to the database. As you can see below, I have hidden elements for certain properties, and my javascript sets the HiddenFor(item.SortOrder) correctly. It then calls the controller. But I would like the entire collection of rows to be passed back as a List<> object. Are there any good examples?

```
@model System.Collections.Generic.IList<PublicationSystem.Model.CustomField>
<table class="table sortable-table"
data-source-href='@Url.RouteUrl("Default",
    new { action = "_CustomFieldSort" },
    Request.Url.Scheme)'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].ColumnName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].ColumnCaption)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    @for (var i=0; i < Model.Count; i++) //each (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model[i].CustomFieldId,new {name="fieldsToEdit["+i+"].CustomFieldId"})
                @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model[i].CustomFormId, new { name = "fieldsToEdit[" + i + "].CustomFormId" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model[i].SortOrder, new { name = "fieldsToEdit[" + i + "].SortOrder", @class = "SortOrder" })
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model[i].ColumnName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model[i].ColumnCaption)
            </td>
            <td>
                ... buttons
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

My javascript:

```
$(".sortable-table tbody").sortable({
    stop: function (event, ui) {

        $(".sortable-table tr").each(function (index, element) {
            var hiddenInput = $(element).find(".SortOrder").first();
            hiddenInput.val(index);
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: $(".sortable-table").attr("data-source-href"),
            method: "POST",
            data: $(".sortable-table").serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
                ClearAndRefresh(); // Assumes parent has this function
            }
        });
    }
});
```

My controller method:

```
public ActionResult _CustomFieldSort(List<CustomField> fieldsToEdit)
{
    if (fieldsToEdit != null) // fieldsToEdit is always null after the sort
    {
        var fieldCount = fieldsToEdit.Count();
    }

    return null;// PartialView();
}
```

I have my javascript correctly trying an ajax call to my controller method, but 'fieldsToEdit' is null. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your hidden field changes when you sorting on client? I just don't understand now, why you put it in table

Comment: why you are saving the sort values in hidden filed ? and what is the significance of saving new sorted values in database ? is it user need to see data based on their old sorting ? normally we are binding these type of data to a grid and enable sort in the columns then it will be simple

Comment: Yeah, no, that's not what we want. The admin wants to have these fields sorted, so that later when they are Viewed on the page by the user, they appear in order. These fields will not be sorted by the user's choice, they will be in a particular order sorted by the Admin.

Answer (score 1):

Bulk update on sorting? using a for loop will enable you to map back the whole list back to a post/get method on the controller

```
@model System.Collections.Generic.IList<PublicationSystem.Model.CustomField>
<table class="table sortable-table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ColumnName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ColumnCaption)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>

@for (int i=0; i < Model.Length;i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model[i].CustomFieldId,new {name="fieldsToEdit["+i+"].CustomFieldId")
            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem =>Model[i].CustomFormId,new {name="fieldsToEdit["+i+"].CustomFormId")
            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model[i].SortOrder, new { @class = "SortOrder",name="fieldsToEdit["+i+"].SortOrder" })
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model[i].ColumnName,new {name="fieldsToEdit["+i+"].ColumnName")
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model[i].ColumnCaption,new {name="fieldsToEdit["+i+"].ColumnCaption")
        </td>
        <td>
            ... buttons
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Then hitting back on button to post button will bulk update the whole list, im not sure if I am answering you question correctly or not though.

Comment: What do you mean 'hitting back on button to post button'? What would the controller method look like?

Comment: Assume you have a model that has a list of your classes; e.g
'Model.ListOfClasses = new List<Classes>();'
Then the countroller will be 

'[httpPost]
public ActionResult YourMethod(List<Classes> ListOfClasses)
{
   //handle your ,model here
}

Note that the default ModelBinder will expect the View to have 
@Html.TexboxFor/HiddenFor,ect (ListOfClasses[Index].yourProperty)

Your list of classes will be mapped back when you post the data

Comment: Okay, I want to pass this back via a javascript ajax call.

Comment: If the data is inside a form, you can use $('#form_element').submit(); 
if the div is not in a form, then set the data for the ajax call as $('divWrapper').serialize();
Where divWrapper is the encompasing div that contains your postback data.

Comment: Thank you. I've updated the code, but it's still not quite right.

Comment: you should generate names that looks like fieldsToEdit[index].YourProperty, you can use `@Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model[i].CustomFieldId,new{name="fieldsToEdit["+i+"].YourProperty"});`

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what you mean.

Comment: I get this: Cannot apply indexing to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<PublicationSystem.Model.CustomField>'

Comment: Change your model to be of List instead of IEnumerable, or any implementation of IList, IEnumrable does no tinclude and indexer, that i sthe reason why you cannot do that, to achieve that you will have to use ElementAt()

Comment: If I do that, the code cannot resolve model.ColumnName in the <th> field.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87603/discussion-between-m-kenyon-ii-and-mahlatse).

Comment: Not sure how to post a two part answer. Mahlatse helped, but I also found another line, I needed to change this: 'data: $(".sortable-table").serialize()' to this: 'data: $(".sortable-table :input").serialize()'.

Comment: best way to do this is to use binding framework such as knockout, kendu, devexpress or others. kendu datasource was very handy for me in this case http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource